# $\mathrm{Ext}_{S}^{m}(S \otimes_{R} M,N)\cong \mathrm{Ext}_{R}^{m}(M,N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $S$ be a flat $R$ algebra.

I want to prove that for any $S$ module $N$ and for any $R$ module $M$, there is an isomorphism $\mathrm{Ext}_{S}^{m}(S \otimes_{R} M,N)\cong \mathrm{Ext}_{R}^{m}(M,N)$.

If $m=0$,it is easy because
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_S(S\otimes_RM,N)\cong \mathrm{Hom}_S\bigl(S,\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,N)\bigr)\cong \mathrm{Hom}_R(M,N)
$$.

How to prove $m>0$?

Comment: I assume it's something like: take a projective resolution $P_\cdot \rightarrow 0$ of $M$. Then $S \otimes P_\cdot$ is a projective resolution of $S \otimes M$. Then compute Ext by taking Hom$(\\_ , N)$. By the same trick as above, you get that this is the same as the sequence Hom($P_\cdot, N)$, the cohomology of which computes Ext$(M,N)$.

Comment: @user113102 Thank you very much!